# sci-kit learn CountVectorizer fit time taken or time estimate

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have around 100k texts in a numpy array.

Is it possible to see the time remaining to complete the fit
or at at least see the amount of fit that has happened
(like `tqdm` for `for`-loops)?

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
cvectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=10, ngram_range=(1,4), max_features=5000)
tvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10, ngram_range=(1,4), max_features=5000)
    
cvectorizer.fit(X_train['essay'].values) 
tvectorizer.fit(X_train['essay'].values)
```

[notebook in limbo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH9jv.png)
[image from assignment designed by: appliedaicourse.com](https://www.appliedaicourse.com)

Comment: Do you want to see the progress of completion?

Comment: sure yes. that would help

Comment: See here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7574